# Contains Syntax for SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm at my wits end here, I'm trying to get this to work

```
Set rex2 = db.OpenRecordset(" Select count(*) from events where event_date >= #" & Format(last_week_start, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# and maildate <= #" & Format(last_week_end, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# and contains(event_type, ""1st call attempted"") and work_ID contains ""UNS"";")
```

where `event_type` is the column name in the database and `work_ID` is also the column name in the database. I've tried it in numerous ways i.e.

```
WHERE event_type contains ""1st Call Attempted"
```

etc but I'm having no luck.

I'd change my code but in event_type there are way too many 1st call attempted categories to list.

I'm also open to using a left statement ie

```
Where left(event_type, 18) = " 1st Call attempted"
```

Anything to get this sodding thing working

Please help me.

Comment: I don't think I understood the `Question`. What are you expecting to get? Explain this one in particular: `there are way too many 1st call attempted categories to list`.

Comment: sorry, I mean that under the field event_types there are many different version of 1st Call attempted, is 1st Call Attempted - No customer Authority, 1st call attempted No answer etc. I want to return anything that starts with 1st Call attempted

Comment: Contains is not used in MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator. You'd need to do something like this:

```sql
... WHERE event_type LIKE '1st Call attempted%' ...
```

and similarly for `work_ID`.

This will match any string that starts with "1st Call attempted" and ends in whatever, since it's like a `*` wildcard. If you executed it in Access, then you'd use a `*` instead of a `%`, but in OLEDB you need to use a `%`.

Comment: It looks like pure MS Access to me, so I would go with `*`, it is `contains` that is the problem, I think.

Comment: Would this apply to DAO method as well?

Comment: @user2308402: Yes, I believe it would.